# How to allow for GUI / Banner at bottom of a scrollview?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[image]Currently I am displaying a list of items to choose from, the scrollview scrolls to the bottom, however, it goes 'under' the GUI/Banner, whereas I would prefer the scrollview to stop displaying beyond that point - the user should still be able to keep scrolling but the scrollview should not overlap the bottom if that makes sense?

At the moment the scrollview takes up the whole screen.

```
- (void)reloadScroll
{
    for(UIView *view in [scroll subviews])
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    
    scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 1760);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int xCoord = 0;
        if(i % 2 == 0)
            xCoord = 57;
        else
            xCoord = 188;
        
        
        UIButton *glasss = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(xCoord, 20 + i/2 * 150 + i/2 * 20, 75, 150)];
        
        if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            int xCoord = 0;
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                xCoord = 156;
            else
                xCoord = 462;
            
            glasss.frame = CGRectMake(xCoord, 20 + i/2 * 300 + i/2 * 20, 150, 300);
            scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, 3240);
        }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using auto-layout?

Comment: Hi Don, it's an older code, for newer work we would of course use auto-layout, but for this it would be easier to modify in place rather than change to auto-layout

Comment: OK - well, it's not at all clear what you mean by *"it goes 'under' the GUI/Banner"*? Additional code and/or an image or two showing the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Added an image, so the dollars, are part of the scrollview, however, whilst they should be scrollable, the scroll view itself should stop when it hits the top of the GUI bar rather than go 'behind it' - of course the scroll should still work, however the frame as such should not go beyond the GUI bar.

Comment: hmmm... a bit confusing. Your code shows you removing all scroll view subviews, but never adding any new subviews? Are the `$` signs buttons? Is the "GUI" view supposed to stay in place, while the `$` buttons slide up/down "underneath" the "GUI" view, or does the "GUI" view also move?